# Redirect in React router dom not redirecting to the given path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a make payment function which is called on a button click and if the user is not signed in i want to redirect that user to the signin component .
This is my code of the function.

```
  const PaymentMethod = ()=>{
        
      if(!isAuthenticated()) 
      {
           toast.error('Please signin to continue');
           history.push('/signin') //works properly
          // return <Redirect to = '/signin' /> // not working properly
           
      }
      
   }

// isAuthenticated is a boolean function that look whether the user is signed in or not
```

Comment: Because components have to render first to take an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return <Redirect to = '/signin' />
```

Because you have to render the `Redirect` to make an effect

Comment: No even this is not working

Comment: It's because you are returning it from function that is called on click. It has to be in DOM. Whatever your onClick function returns is simply ignored and does nothing.

Comment: I thought that `PaymentMethod` is a component. Naming convension would suggest that

Answer (score 0):

If `PaymentMethod` a React component, then the `history.push` needs to be called in a `useEffect` hook with proper dependency or in a callback function as an *intentional* side-effect, not as an unintentional side-effect in the render body. The `Redirect` component would need to be returned from the component in order to have any effect.

`useEffect` Example to issue imperative redirect:

```
const PaymentMethod = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
      toast.error('Please sign in to continue');
      history.replace('/signin');
    }
  }, [history, toast]);
    
  ...
};
```

`<Redirect>` Example to issue declarative redirect:

```
const PaymentMethod = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
      toast.error('Please sign in to continue'); // <-- still a side-effect!!
    }
  }, [toast]);
    
  if (!isAuthenticated()) {
    return <Redirect to='/signin' />;
  }

  ... regular JSX return ...
};
```

If `PaymentMethod` ***is*** the callback function then it ***must*** issue the imperative redirect via the `history.replace` function, returning JSX from an asynchronously called callback doesn't render it to the DOM. You should also not name the callback handler like it's a React function component. This is to remove any confusion.

```
const history = useHistory();

...

const paymentMethodHandler = () => {
  if (!isAuthenticated()) {
    toast.error('Please sign in to continue');
    history.replace('/signin');
  }
};

...
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `<Redirect to = '/signin' />` is a component and not a JS that can be called. Components need to be rendered in order for their JS to run.

If you for some reason want to specifically use redirect component you will have to put it into DOM on click.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use `useNavigate()` hook.
[example](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

```
 const PaymentMethod = () =>{
    
  if(!isAuthenticated()) 
  {
       toast.error('Please signin to continue');
       history.push('/signin')
       useNavigate('/signin')
       
  }
```

}

Comment: You may want to re-review the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Only call hooks at the top level, don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or ***nested functions***, i.e. `paymentMethod`. In addition to this, the `useNavigate` hook doesn't take any arguments ***and*** is a RRDv6 hook. Since OP is referencing a `history` object it is very likely the case they are ***not*** using RRDv6.